# positivity of (1,1) forms

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

According to [p131 corollary 1.7](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf), a (1,1) form $u = i u_{ij} dz_i \wedge d\bar z_j$ is positive if $(u_{ij})$ is a positive semi definite matrix.

However according to definition (1.1), $\frac{u^n}{n!} = det(u_{ij})dx_1\wedge dy_1 \ldots \wedge dx_n \wedge dy_n$ should be positive, which is not necessarily true because the derterminant  might be zero. What is wrong here?

Comment: Note that the author distinguishes between *positive* and *strongly positive*. You're thinking about the strongly positive case.

Comment: how is $u^n$ a convex combination?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: My apologies, I am trying to understand what you mean. From what I understand, an $(n,n)$ form is positive if it is consistent with the natural orientation on the complex manifold. I am merely checking the positivity of $\frac{u^n}{n!}$ using this. One cannot use the author's definition to check the positivity of $(n, n)$ forms since it is based on it in my opinion.

Comment: I'm saying that if $u$ is strongly positive, then the determinant will be positive. I've always used the term positive to mean strictly positive. I think most complex geometers do that.

Comment: I see. Just to clarify. The reason that this $u^n$ is not positive does not disprove that $u$ is positive is that $u^n$ is not of the form $u  \wedge ia_1 \wedge \bar a_1 \wedge \ldots ia_{n-1} \wedge \bar a_{n-1}$. So by definition, $u$ being positive would not imply that $u^n$ is positive.